I found this fuzzy spider type pest in alberta canada. I cannot find it online. Can anyone help identify it?
Tiny fuzz like critter on
My bathroom wall. Appears to have some blue on it. The rest is white. It seems to have a lot of legs , almost tentacle like?


Welcome Erin. Did you mean to post a picture? You can use the [edit] button to add one now.
